# vim command for search and substitute

Tags: vim

This is my question.

In vim editor I want to select all the words between double quotes through out the whole file and i want to replace the selected words by preceding that with gettext string. Please anybody tell me vim command to do this.

for ex:
if the file contains

printf("first string\n");
printf("second string\n");

After replacement my file should like this

printf(gettext("first string\n"));
printf(gettext("second string\n"));

Answer (score 1):

try this in vim:

```
:%s/\(".*"\)/gettext(\1)/g
```

Here `\(` and `\)` is being used to group the text and `\1` is then used to put 1st [backreference](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions) back along with `gettext` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
s/\".\{-}\"/gettext\(\1\)/g
```

Answer (score 1):

in command mode:

```
:%s!"\([^"]*\)"!gettext("\1")!g
```

the `%` is for whole document, `[^"]*` for anything except quotes, and the `g` at the end for all occurence in the line (default is only the first one). The separator char can be anything not in the regexp... I often use `!` rather than `/` (more convenient when dealing with path e.g.)